# WEB3 send Transaction deduct fees

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I'm using WEB3 version 4.0.3

for example i want to send 0.1 ETH.

so to send that i need Gas.

so what i try to do is:

The current amount to send minus the fees
(0.1 - 0.000003 for example)

But i always get:

> insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0xb97170623721F86E7d9756E72668f9A209A4e8Ad have 10124457040804150 want 11032599524271312

```
app.post('/send', async (request, response) => {

    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
    const gasLimit = 21000;

    const from = 'FROM_ADDRESS';
    const to = 'TO_ADDRESS';
    const amount = utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether').toString() - gasPrice.toString();
    const privateKey = 'PRIVATE_KEY';

    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(from, 'latest');

    const txObject = {
        from: from,
        to: to,
        value: amount,
        gasPrice: gasPrice,
        gas: gasLimit,
        nonce: nonce,
    };

    web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txObject, privateKey)
        .then(signedTx => {
            web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
                .on('receipt', receipt => {
                    console.log(receipt);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            ;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            error('something went wrong', response);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your want to send a value (e.g. `0.1 ether`) your account balance must be:

```
ACCOUNT_BALANCE <= (VALUE + GAS_PRICE * GAS_LIMIT)
```

1. You subtracting the `gasPrice`, but you have to multiply the gas price by the gas limit you use, as the price is for 1 gas unit.
2. It looks like you don't have enough balance to send, so if you want to send the complete balance, you have to subtract the amount which will be used for gas.

```js
const gasPrice = BigInt(await web3.eth.getGasPrice());
const gasLimit = 21000n;
const balance = BigInt(await web3.eth.getBalance(from));
// send all
const amount = balance - gasPrice * gasLimit;
if (amount <= 0n) {
    throw new Error("Not enough balance to send ${balance}");
}
const value = '0x' + amount.toString(16);
```

Comment: thx for your reply.  that's the best way to do that?

Comment: and why to use BigInt? it's no better to use the web3 utils?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about best/worst. The keypoint is, that you must multiply `gasPrice` by `gasLimit`.  Technically how to do this, is up to you. The `BigInt` is the new built-in javascript type - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt I prefer this over the old BigNumber libraries.

Comment: thx, also the "const value = '0x' + amount.toString(16);"., should i change it also to that?

Comment: I think yes, as I know, web3js doesn't support native BigInts, so you can't pass it in your `txObject`, so you have to serialize it to the hex string.